# Applying multiple CAGradientLayer to mask a view

Tags: ios, swift, view, mask, cagradientlayer

I have a view with gradient layer mask to apply a fade effect from top down and from bottom up, the code looks something like:

```
gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = label.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
gradient.locations = [0, 0.1, 0.9, 1]
view.layer.mask = gradient
```

Now I want to add another gradient layer to also add fade out from left to right effect.

Since "mask" can get only 1 layer I have tried to create another CAGradientLayer() and add it as a sub layer to the vertical gradient which didn't work.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to add multiple layers

```
 view.layer.insertSublayer(youLayer, at: 0)
```